# How to print List of String array array using lambda in Java

Tags: java, java-8, java-11

This is my code:

```
List<String[]> salaries = getSalariesByMonth();

//I am using the old way to print the data
for (String[] obj : rates) {
    System.out.println("User name: "obj[0]+"--"+"Salary: "+obj[1]);   //obj[0] is NAME,  obj[1] is SALARY
}

//I am trying to use this way to print the data but unable to do so.
salaries.forEach(s-> System.out.println("print NAME and SALARY"));
```

How to print the List that contains String array using Lambda. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, what is blocking you in the lambda? What did you try? What's.not working?

Comment: I am trying to use r[0], r[1] in lambda but it is not working. Don't know how to get the data from r.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To convert a for-each loop into a `forEach` call the general pattern is:

```java
for (final var x : xs) {
  statements;
}
// becomes:
xs.forEach(x -> { statements; });
// with a single statement, braces are optional:
xs.forEach(x -> statement);
```

A lambda of the form `(x, y) -> { statements; }` is mostly equivalent to a method of the form:

```java
… yourMethod(final … x, final … y) {
  statements;
}
```

Return type and parameter type are inferred automatically by the compiler when a lambda is encountered.

---

So in your case that would be:

```java
salaries.forEach(obj -> System.out.println("User name: "+obj[0]+"--"+"Salary: "+obj[1]));
```

You could also use streams to first map each object to a string representation and then output each item in a terminal operation:

```java
salaries.stream()
        .map(obj -> "User name: "+obj[0]+"--"+"Salary: "+obj[1])
        .forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

Since `System.out.println` expects exactly one argument which matches the lambda argument, it could be replaced with a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), which can be more readable in some cases: `.forEach(System.out::println)`

Comment: @AlexRudenko: thanks, the concatenated string was copied verbatim from the question :)

Answer (score 2):

```java
salaries.stream()
        .map(salary -> String.format("User name: %s -- Salary: %s", salary[0], salary[1]))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```